# PHP join arrays according to date

Tags: php

I am trying to join the arrays according to when the dates are the same

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 14
            [enter1] => 2024-01-14 15:46:58
            [exit1] => 2024-01-14 19:46:58
            [group1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 15
            [enter1] => 2024-01-15 15:47:58
            [exit1] => 2024-01-15 15:51:11
            [group1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 15
            [enter2] => 2024-01-15 18:11:33
            [exit2] => 2024-01-15 19:11:33
            [group2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (            
            [date] => 15
            [enter3] => 2024-01-15 15:48:22
            [exit3] => 2024-01-15 17:25:43
            [group3] => 3
        )

)
```

I would like to join them by [date] = 15 and have them look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 14
            [enter2] => 2024-01-14 15:46:58
            [exit2] => 2024-01-14 19:46:58
            [group] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 15
            [enter1] => 2024-01-15 15:47:58
            [exit1] => 2024-01-15 15:51:11
            [group] => 1
            [enter2] => 2024-01-15 18:11:33
            [exit2] => 2024-01-15 19:11:33
            [group] => 2
            [enter3] => 2024-01-15 15:48:22
            [exit3] => 2024-01-15 17:25:43
            [group] => 3
        )

)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to join them with array_merge() without success

Comment: Please present your input data in "usable" form - as code. Either the result of a `var_dump`, or in form of JSON.

Comment: Will the entries always be sorted by date in ascending order, or is that not a given?

Comment: What had you tried so far? please share the code

Comment: Your result has in your example 3 times a key named "group". I guess you meant "group1" "group2" and "group3"

Answer (score 1):

There is no php function that does exactly what you want to achieve, so let's iterate the array and do the work by hand.

```
$input = [
  [
      "date" => 14,
      "enter1" => strtotime("2024-01-14 15:46:58"),
      "exit1" => strtotime("2024-01-14 19:46:58"),
      "group1" => 2
  ],
  [
      "date" => 15,
      "enter1" => strtotime("2024-01-15 15:47:58"),
      "exit1" => strtotime("2024-01-15 15:51:11"),
      "group1" => 1
  ],
  [
      "date" => 15,
      "enter2" => strtotime("2024-01-15 18:11:33"),
      "exit2" => strtotime("2024-01-15 19:11:33"),
      "group2" => 2
  ],
  [
      "date" => 15,
      "enter3" => strtotime("2024-01-15 15:48:22"),
      "exit3" => strtotime("2024-01-15 17:25:43"),
      "group3" => 3
  ]
];


function my_array_reduce($input) {
    $output = [];
    foreach($input as $in) {
        if(isset($output[$in["date"]])) {
            $output[$in["date"]] = array_merge($output[$in["date"]], $in);
        } else {
            $output[$in["date"]] = $in;
        }
    }
    return array_values($output);
}

print_r(my_array_reduce($input));
```

The trick is to collect records in a new array `$output` where the date value is the array key. This way it, when iterating the input, it is easy to check if  a date already has been collected using `isset()`. `array_merge` helps to combine two sub-arrays with the same date. In the end `array_values()` removes the date keys.